# Binding data to treeView c#

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I wish my program worked like this:
1.It takes data form MS SQL
2.Makes tree based on this data(data rows)
3.I have few textBoxex and I want to fill them with data based on clicked node.
I`ve made class for SQL connection:

```
 class Baza
{
    private SqlConnection connection;
    string dbdir = "Data Source=CS24\\SQLEXPRESS;user id=sa;password=alamakota;database=SHARP;connection timeout=3";
    public Baza()
    {
      connection = new SqlConnection();
      connection.ConnectionString = dbdir;
      connection.Open();
    }
    public DataTable get_data(string q) 
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
        SqlDataReader dr ; 
        SqlCommand sqlc = new SqlCommand(q);
        sqlc.Connection = this.connection;
        dr = sqlc.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(dr);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

And treeView creator:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Baza baza = new Baza();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = baza.get_data("Select * from Users order by Id asc");
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) 
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["Name"].ToString() + " " + dr["Surname"].ToString());
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
```

I thought that node should have ID which I can use to make data filling but I dont really know how to do it. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Are the hierarchical data present in the database, if so how ? ( i meant the parent-child relation ships for the treeView)

Comment: For now I`ve created only one table with some basic information about users. In treeView I want to have only Name and Surname.When I click on a person(on treeView) I wish rest of data show in TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble and i did this :

(I had hierarchical data in columns ParentID, IsGroup, OrderInGroup)

- Create a class for the TreeViewItems

  ```
   public class xTreeViewItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public int parent;
        public List<xTreeViewItem > children { get; set; }
        public bool isGroup = false;
        public bool ParentResolved = false;
        public float order {get;set;}

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
             if (PropertyChanged != null)
             {
                   PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
             }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   }
  ```
- Now make a list with the SQL Data

  ```
  private void LoadTree()
  {
      ObservableCollection<xTreeViewItem> treeSource = new ObservableCollection<xTreeViewItem>();
      List<xTreeViewItem> Buffer = new List<xTreeViewItem>();
      foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
      {
           xTreeViewItem itm = new TreeViewItem();
           // Load the required heirarchial data
           Buffer.Add(itm);
      }

      for (int i = Buffer.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
          if (Buffer[i].parentID != 0)
          {
              if (Buffer[i].ParentResolved)
                  Buffer.RemoveAt(i);
              else
              {
                  Buffer[i].ParentResolved = true;

                  while (Buffer.Any(c => (c.parentID == Buffer[i].menuID && !c.ParentResolved)))
                  {
                      Buffer[i].children.Add(FindChildren(Buffer[i]));
                  }
                  xTreeViewItem parent = Buffer.First(c => c.menuID == Buffer[i].parentID);
                  parent.children.Add(Buffer[i]);
                  Buffer[i].parent = parent;

                  Buffer.RemoveAt(i);
              }
          }
      }
      // remaining items acts as mainItems, so add it to the treeSource
      foreach (xTreeViewItem x in Buffer)
      {
           treeSource.Add(x);
      }
      treeView.ItemsSource = treeSource;
  }

  xTreeViewItem FindChildren(xMenuItem x)
  {
      List<xTreeViewItem > subBuffer = Buffer.Where(c => (c.parentID == x.menuID && !c.ParentResolved)).ToList(); // if there is, get all of them to a list

      subBuffer = subBuffer.OrderBy(c => c.order).ToList();    // << THIS IS CRAZY, BUT FIXES :P // order all of them by their 'order' property
      int indx = Buffer.IndexOf(subBuffer[0]);                                                    // get the first item after ordering

      Buffer[indx].ParentResolved = true;
      Buffer[indx].parent = x;                // changing parentresolved property to prevent infinte loops

      while (Buffer.Any(c => (c.parentID == Buffer[indx].menuID && !c.ParentResolved))) // again checking if the current child got any other child.
      {
          Buffer[indx].children.Add(FindChildren(Buffer[indx])); // adding all the childs                     
      }

      return Buffer[indx]; // return the child

  }
  ```

In XAML : put this as the TreeView's ItemTemplate :)

```
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
          <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding children}">
                  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header}" Margin="2,0"/>
          </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

This did the work for me :P
and to get the selected item, just use :

```
xTreeViewItem selectedItem = (xTreeViewItem)treeView.SelectedItem;
```

make your view update with this 'selectedItem'; .. :)

Hope it helped :)

** Sometimes the items may appear reversed. Simply give the List.Reverse(); in the point where it is so, i havent run the code myself, anyway this should work for all types, like loading MenuItems from Database and desplaying (useful if you have multiple languages) :)

** Im just 18 yrs old :P havent got a degree in CS, this is just a code that i came up with :) yea there might be flaws but it works for me :P

:)

Comment: OMG I thought there is a easier way;) I dont understand everything what you wrote here.

Comment: What i did is that, loaded everything to a List named Buffer first, then from it took each one from the bottom and tried adding to its parent and delete from the buffer, before deleting, it would check for any child items it could have, and that child searches for its child and so on till it ends.. Give a slow reading through the code :) you would get it :)